# How to delay(e.g. animate) the removal of React elements when their Redux store data is removed instantly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Sorry for asking without particular code examples for they may confuse with complexity and lead away from the point.

Let's say we have an array of records in the redux store that is represented by a list of connected react elements.

Saying "connected" I mean:

```js
export connect(store => {/* list binding here */})(RecordsListComponent)
```

Then some action dispatched on store instantly removes a record and the list component is updated (re-rendered).

Now I have an intention to animate deleted records so they disappeared from DOM with a delay. What's the best (clear, compact, flexible and reliable) approach to make this?

Answer (score 0):

One of obvious ideas is to use `useEffect` and `useState` hooks that will allow to keep the previous state of the list and analyse the diff with current state in props.

So the list component will be able to internally determine intermediate records' states (spawning, present, vanishing, etc.) and change them at it's own discretion.

Though, I don't know if this approach will be expensive on large lists...

Comment: Here some more instructions on handling changes in props.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state